# How to make CMake exit non-0 in response to warning "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project"?

Tags: c++, jenkins, cmake, warnings

Is there a way to make CMake exit with a non-0 exit code in response to warning "Manually-specified variables were not used by the project"?

[image]

I'm fond of rigorous programming with maximum warnings and warnings treated as errors, yet in the presence of this CMake warning, which if uncaught early in certain build pipelines can cause surprising failures down the road, possible fix [`-Werror=dev`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake.1.html#options) does not trigger a non-0 CMake exit code and `--no-warn-unused-cli` is the opposite of what I'm looking for.

As a workaround to CMake appearing to not support this feature, I adorn my C++ Jenkins jobs with [Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) checks for "CMake Warning" to fail the build if that string is found in build output.

[image: Jenkins TextFinder Plugin]

Comment: Can you please show how you are calling CMake in Jenkins? Does it work if there are "real errors" in the CMake script files like a syntax error?

Comment: I'm calling CMake in Jenkins using command "cmake -Werror=dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DAddressSanitizerMode=ON .." , which indeed works to detect real errors such as syntax errors. This question arose from realizing that if "-DAddressSanitizerMode=ON" were to one day be misspelled, CMake would kindly exit 0, addresses would go unsanitized, and a memory leak that would otherwise be caught by -fsanitize=address could be deployed to production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the code and you can't turn this `Warning` into an error. If you look at [`cmake::RunCheckForUnusedVariables()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L2488) it issues a

- WARNING

  - `CMake Warning ...`

and not a

- AUTHOR_WARNING

  - `CMake Warning (dev) ...`

So you can't elevate normal warnings to errors through a command line option.

The command line call will always return `0` in those cases.

Either you change the CMake's source code or you rewrite the unused variables check inside CMake script code.